# How to convert the tapply function into a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a function that is supposed to work like tapply() but I can't seem to get it working right. I need to use a for loop this.

```
baby.tapply = function(X, INDEX, FUN) {
  z = 0
 for(y in levels(factor(INDEX))){
   z = FUN(X)
 }
  return(z)
}

baby.tapply(X=mtcars$mpg, INDEX=mtcars$cyl, FUN=mean)

#Should mimic this: 
tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, mean)
```

Any suggestions from where to go from here? 
My output: 
20.090625 
        1

Correct Output (from tapply)
       4        6        8 
26.66364 19.74286 15.10000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to mimic `tapply` with `for` loop :

```
baby.tapply = function(X, INDEX, FUN) {

  lvls <- levels(factor(INDEX))
   z <- numeric(length(lvls))
   for(y in seq_along(lvls)){
       z[y] = FUN(X[INDEX == lvls[y]])
    }
    return(setNames(z, lvls))
}

baby.tapply(X=mtcars$mpg, INDEX=mtcars$cyl, FUN=mean)
#      4        6        8 
#26.66364 19.74286 15.10000 

#Comparing with the output of tapply
tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, mean)
#       4        6        8 
#26.66364 19.74286 15.10000
```

As mentioned by @Onyambu probably it is better to initialize `z` as list and not a vector

```
z <- vector("list",length(lvls))
```

for functions such as `range` which return two values.

Comment: technically, `z` should be a a list. ie `z <- vector("list",length(lvls))`. What if you pass a function like `range`?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.